# Throw new NullPointerException VS invoking method on null object

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I want to test my application and check if it handles NullPointerExceptions correctly.

I have two ideas how to do this:

```
throw new NullPointerException();
```

and:

```
((Object) null).hashCode();
```

They both produce the identical stacktrace.

The second one is "more real" to me, because this is what would happen in my real code.

Is there any difference between those two statements?
Which should i use?

Comment: There is no difference, the stacktrace should look slightly different though.

Comment: no stacktrace looks identical

Comment: Oh right stacktrace it is the same. `throw null;` would btw work as well (I think because it's NPE'ing in the throw) but I'd use the explicit version since that is expressing your intention clearly and you will not ask yourself later what you did there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use directly

```
throw new NullPointerException();
```

Because,JRE  throws [NullPointerException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) when

- **Calling the instance method of a null object.**
- Accessing or modifying the field of a null object.
- Taking the length of null as if it were an array.
- Accessing or modifying the slots of null as if it were an array.
- Throwing null as if it were a Throwable value.

When you do this

```
((Object) null).hashCode();
```

You met the first condition and JRE throws the `NPE.`

**Finally You are increasing one more step. That's it. No Difference.**

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
throw new NullPointerException();
```

because you want to test if your application hanldes a `NullPointerException` correctly.

Comment: that's true! but what i really want to test is what happens when a method is called on a null object and if my application handles it correct

Comment: Well, that's what happens. The JRE will throw a new NullPointerException.

Comment: @PhilippSander yes, I understand you. But when a method is called on a null object the jvm throws just a NullPointerException. So I don't see a benefit of causing a NullPointerException and let it be thrown by the jvm and just throw it by yourself in the test.

Comment: this answer is really good, but i've chosen sureshs because of the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Both lines of code throw an identical exception, as documented. Unless you want to test the JRE / Java (which is totally unnecessary) there is no difference between both lines in terms of a test strategy.